# Error when formatting flash drive: read-only

Tags: gparted, usb-drive, nfs, read-only

I got this error when trying to format a USB flash drive using GParted.

```
Error formatting volume

  Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdb1"'   
  exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1:   
  probing initialization failed: Read-only file system  
  (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

[image: Error while formatting USB flash drive]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wipefs failed because the USB flash drive is mounted. Run `lsblk` to check whether the flash drive is mounted, and run this command to unmount it if needed:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Then try to format the flash drive in GParted again.